How Can I find NullAway Warning?
I'm installing NullAway into my project.
I don't want compile to stop by NullAway error, because there is too many NullAway error for now.
Instead, I want to know NPE potential with WARNING, but I cannot find warning log from Nullaway.
How can I solve it?
Here is my pom.
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-XDcompilePolicy=simple</arg>
                        <arg>-Xplugin:ErrorProne -Xep:NullAway:ERROR
                            -XepOpt:NullAway:AnnotatedPackages=com.example.springdemo -XepExcludedPaths:.*/src/test/java/.*
                        </arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>error_prone_core</artifactId>
                            <version>${error_prone.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.uber.nullaway</groupId>
                            <artifactId>nullaway</artifactId>
                            <version>${nullaway.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

I changed compilerArgs.
It expected log 'WARNING' about NullAway. But I cannot find them.
Please tell me how can I fix it.
